# convert ssis expression datetime to int

Tags: sql-server, datetime, ssis, expression, etl

I want to calculate last friday's date in ssis. Below code is doing it.

```
DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", getdate()) % 7), getdate())
```

But it gives results for datetime datatype and I want results for int data type in ssis.

How to convert?

```
DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", getdate()) % 7), getdate())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression):

> When a string is cast to a DT_DATE, or vice versa, the locale of the transformation is used. However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format.

In order to convert value to integer `yyyyMMdd`,

1. First you have to convert the value to a string
2. Get the first 10 digit
3. Remove the `-` separator
4. Convert to integer.

You can use the following expression:

```
(DT_I4)REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", getdate()) % 7), getdate()),1,10),"-","")
```