# ssis expression for adding time to date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, ssis, etl

Add time value

I have date value coming from some variable in ssis. I want to add 8 pm time stamp in this date. how to do that?

```sql
DECLARE @a  int
SET @a = 20190611
--SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME,   CONVERT(DATE, CAST(CAST(@a AS INT) AS CHAR(8)), 112)  , @a)
SELECT DATEADD("hh", 20,CONVERT(DATETIME,   CONVERT(DATE, CAST(CAST(@a AS INT) AS CHAR(8)), 112)  , @a) )
```

I need to convert this expression to SSIS compatible format.

Comment: Are you sure that the issue is solved? Can you provide the expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your variable is a datetime and has some time

First truncate the time (via cast) and then add 20 hours.

Here is the formula for another variable:

```
DATEADD("hh",20, (DT_DATE)(DT_DBDATE)GETDATE())
```

Result:
6/14/2019 8:00:00 PM

Simply replace getdate() with your variable.

Comment: Thanks but as you can see in the code, the variable is int format. so we need to conver it as well.

Comment: "I have date value coming from some variable in ssis."  I will provide an update.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply convert to string and concatenate with `200000` and reconvert to integer to obtain `yyyyMmddHHmmss` format:

```
(DT_I4)((DT_WSTR,20)@[User::DateIntegerVariable] + "200000")
```

If this question is related to your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550831/convert-ssis-expression-datetime-to-int) then use the following:

```
(DT_I4)(REPLACE(SUBSTRING((DT_WSTR,50)DATEADD("dd", -1 - (DATEPART("dw", getdate()) % 7), getdate()),1,10),"-","") + "200000")
```